# Get certificate detail from public key?

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

Is there any way to get certificate detail from public key? I had to use Bouncy Castle jar for this but somehow I can't solve this problem.

Comment: You cannot get certificate information from the public key. Public key itself is a part of the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the openssl toolkit to inspect certificates:

```
$ openssl x509 -in /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/cacert.org.crt -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
...
```

If you need the results in another environment, you may need to give more details.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for reply me,
actually i am using java, so if possible then can u focus me on in java , how would be i will get certificate detail from Public key..?

Comment: Okay :) it's been a while since I did Java, but here's the starting point I remember using: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html